# How to "deepcopy" 2d list in python without import

Tags: python

I currently have a 2d matrix

```
matrix =    [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
             ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
             ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.'],
             ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.']]
```

And I've assigned `copy = matrix` to make a copy of the matrix.
However, I ran into a bug where when I modify `copy[]`, it also modifies `matrix[]`.
I found out that this is a side effect with aliasing and I need to create a deep copy of `matrix[]`.

How do I create a deep copy of a 2d matrix without using imports?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/3001761 shows various options, assignment is **not** copying.

Comment: Why would you not want to import [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)? It's part of the Python standard library so you won't need to install anything.

Comment: @DMalan From a learning standpoint, accomplishing tasks without importing any modules seems reasonable.

Comment: `[sub.copy() for sub in matrix]` or any equivalent. This actually isn't a bad thing to do, `copy.deepcopy` is resource intensive because it takes some care to do this correctly for arbitrary inputs (even just avoiding infinite loops). If you have a known structure, it isn't unreasonable to write some deep copy function/ method for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a 2D array like your matrix, this should work:

```py
def deep_copy(A):
    return [r[:] for r in A]
```

It's equivalent to looping over each inner list and copying each of the inner lists. If the values in the inner lists are mutable, this doesn't sufficiently deep-copy but for your use case it should be fine. There's also `[[v for v in r] for r in A]`, which manually copies instead of using a slice to do so.

EDIT: there's also a more general recursive approach that works for your case of using lists of immutable values:

```py
def deep_copy_r(v):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        return [deep_copy_r(e) for e in v]
    return v
```

Said recursive approach will work up to arbitrary array dimensionality (works for a 3D array, 4D array, up to an N-D array), but only works if lists are the only containing type used.

Comment: Careful here. Depending on your input, this can loop forever

Comment: Is there a case where this would infinitely loop given that the inputs only use containing lists?

Comment: No, this can work if your are dealing with well behaved inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to assign a copy of each list in `matrix` into the other list:

```
matrix = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
          ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
          ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
          ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
          ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.']]

matrix2 = [l.copy() for l in matrix]

matrix[0][0] = 'O'

print(matrix)
print(matrix2)
```

Output:

```
[['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.']]
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop.

```
m1 = []
for inner in matrix:
    m1.append([])
    for elem in inner:
        m1[-1].append(elem)

print(m1)
```

This should do the trick. Using list comprehension is a step up to do this, but you should simply use `deepcopy()` to begin with.

Comment: Looping and appending isn't idiomatic or particularly performant.

Comment: @jonsharpe fully agree - but suits the knowledgelevel of the asker and the arbitraty restriction to not use deepcopy

Comment: Just a little note: The colon in *"You can use a simple loop:"* needs to be a dot.